# Regular Expression match special colon

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have the following string :

```
string x = "abc<ee:dd>\r\nHERE:we<pp>xq:zxcv<qq>";
```

I want to write a regular expression to find the first `:` which is not in a `<>` block.

Ideally, I want to get the parts before and after the first `:`

That is:

```
string y ="abc<ee:dd>\r\nHERE"

string z = "we<pp>xq:zxcv<qq>"
```

How can I match the part before the first `:`?

I am new to Regex and tried a lot, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because NSRegularExpressions don't have variable length look-behinds, we need to get a little creative.

The following should work:

```
(.*?):(?![^<]*>)(.*)
```

### Breakdown:

`(.*?):` Match all characters until the first colon

`(?![^<]*>)(.*)` In order for this first colon to be accepted, we do a negated look-ahead to make sure there is no closing bracket `>` **without** an opening bracket in front. If this turns out to be true, we know that this colon is not inside brackets.

Comment: Yep, take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are tricky... not only do you have to know what to match, but also what not to match.  For this case, I tested this expression at https://regex101.com/ and got the desired result:

```
^(.*<.*>.*):(.*)$/U
```

The brackets () are the key here to make two groups that match on either side of the colon that is not within the angled brackets <>.

Comment: This has the same problem where if you have the following it won't work: `abc<ee:dd>\r\nHERE<ee:dd>TEST:we<pp>xq:zxcv<qq>` (two pairs of <> <> in front of the first colon)

Comment: Hence the comment that you have to know what not to match.  Only the author of the question will know for sure.  There's no shortage of different input strings that won't work.